# Error SQLiteException: foreign key mismatch

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite

Estaba haciendo una base de datos, pero después de horas de revisión no pude llegar a una resolución a mi problema, por lo que acudo a ustedes en busca de una respuesta.

Quería hacer una consulta de una base de datos, cuyas tablas son las siguientes:

```
    db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("calificaciones.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists usuarios (idusuario integer primary key autoincrement, nusuario text, contrasena text, correo text);");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists alumnos (idalumno integer primary key, apellidos text, nalumno text, especialidad text, grado text, grupo text);");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists materias (idmateria integer primary key, nmateria text,"+" docente text, horas integer);");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists calificacion (idcalif integer primary key autoincrement, idalumno integer, idmateria integer, idusuario integer, calificacion integer, parcial integer, foreign key(idalumno) references alumnos(idalumno), foreign key(idmateria) references materias(idmateria), foreign key(idusuario) references alumnos(idusuario));");
```

Pero, al momento de querer ingresar un registro dentro de la tabla "Calificación", ésta me proporciona el mensaje de error siguiente:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: foreign key mismatch - "calificacion" referencing "alumnos" (code 1): , while compiling: insert into calificacion (idalumno, idmateria, idusuario, calificacion, parcial) values (15330050790409,42069,1,10,3);
```

a pesar de que en los registros de las otras tablas la llave primaria coincide con los datos tratados de introducir en el insert.

Intenté reproducir el error en SQL Fiddle, ya que en éste podía verificar tablas, y a pesar de usar exactamente los mismos Querys, en SQL Fiddle sí funcionó, a pesar de que en mi aplicación por más que intenté hacer no funcionó.

Soy bastante nuevo en Android Studio y es parte de un proyecto final, así que si alguien supiera una solución se lo agradecería bastante.

**EDIT:** La función la cual ocurre el error es la siguiente, en caso de que sea un error externo a la base de datos:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    IntIdmateria=Integer.parseInt(ETPC3idmateria.getText().toString().trim());
    IntIdusuario=Integer.parseInt(ETPC3idusuario.getText().toString().trim());
    IntCalificacion=Integer.parseInt(ETPC3calificacion.getText().toString().trim());
    IntParcial=Integer.parseInt(ETPC3parcial.getText().toString().trim());
    LongIdalumno=Long.parseLong(ETPC3idalumno.getText().toString().trim());
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.BTNPC3insertarcalificacion:{
            cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from alumnos where idalumno="+LongIdalumno+";", null);
            cursor2=db.rawQuery("select * from materias where idmateria="+IntIdmateria+";", null);
            cursor3=db.rawQuery("select * from usuarios where idusuario="+IntIdusuario+";", null);
            if(LongIdalumno==0 || IntIdmateria==0 || IntIdusuario==0 || IntCalificacion==0 || IntParcial==0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "No ha llenado todos los datos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if(cursor.getCount()==0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se ha encontrado ese Número de Control",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if(cursor2.getCount()==0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se ha encontrado esa identificación de Materia",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if(cursor3.getCount()==0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "No se ha encontrado esa identificación de Usuario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if(LongIdalumno!=0 && IntIdmateria!=0 && IntIdusuario!=0 && IntCalificacion!=0 && IntParcial!=0){
                db.execSQL("insert into calificacion (idalumno, idmateria, idusuario, calificacion, parcial) values ("+LongIdalumno+","+IntIdmateria+","+IntIdusuario+","+IntCalificacion+","+IntParcial+");");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha insertado la calificación correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parece que es un problema del campo que tengas como foreign key. Te paso un enlace [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144418/5675636] por si te sirve de ayuda

Comment: Prueba a definir los ids que declaras como foreign key en la tabla como UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0):

En un principio parece que todo este correcto, ya que las estructuras de las tablas parecen correctas y además estás activando el flag que te permite tener activas las `foreign keys` en [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) según la [documentación](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Por otro lado el único motivo que veo por el que te esté fallando es porque  el `idalumno` que tu pones en el insert `15330050790409` esté repetido y no sea un valor único, y esto podría ser posible porque según la estructura de tu tabla no se está generando automáticamente con el `autoincrement` y podría ser que hubieras introducido algún valor duplicado.

Comment: Ningún registro se ha duplicado, ya que tengo planeado para evitar casos como esos, incluso intenté verificar desinstalando y volviendo a instalar la aplicación, para reiniciar la base de datos desde cero, pero igual sigue marcando ese error.

Comment: pues si que es algo extraño, porque parece estar todo correcto en la estructura de base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Revisa como esta definida tu columna `idcalif`, es una `primary key` autoincrementable :

```
db.execSQL("create table if not exists calificacion (idcalif integer primary key autoincrement, idalumno integer, idmateria integer, idusuario integer, calificacion integer, parcial integer, foreign key(idalumno) references alumnos(idalumno), foreign key(idmateria) references materias(idmateria), foreign key(idusuario) references alumnos(idusuario));");
```

por lo tanto **no debes enviarle el valor de `idcalif` o intentar modificar el valor de la columna, ya que se calcula automáticamente**, tu query debe ser de esta forma:

```
 db.execSQL("insert into calificacion (idmateria, idusuario, calificacion, parcial) values ("+IntIdmateria+","+IntIdusuario+","+IntCalificacion+","+IntParcial+");");
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de tener el mismo error y ya se resolvio, me parece que a ti te estaria pasando lo mismo.

Resulta que en mis tablas la primera columna -usualmente llamada id(+algo) v.gr idEstudiante-, y que es generalmente un integer, primary key yo no habia puesto "autoincrement"

lo hice y ya puedo insertar datos sin ese error

la misma db la tengo en DB Browser for SQLite (se descarga gratis) ejecute un PRAGMA foreign_key_check; y no me arrojo ninguna discrepancia ejemplo

```
CREATE TABLE "treatments" (
"idtreatment"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
"dateapp"   INTEGER,
"brand" TEXT,
"lot"   TEXT,
"expdate"   TEXT,
"patientid" INTEGER,
"datamedic" TEXT,
"signature" INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY("iddossier" AUTOINCREMENT), // <---- aqui
CONSTRAINT "fk_dossiers_patiens" FOREIGN KEY("patientid") REFERENCES "patients"("idpatient") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE "patients" (
"idpatient" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"name"  TEXT,
"trtmnt_kind"   INTEGER,
"gender"    I
"birthdate" INTEGER,
"treatmentid"   INTEGER,
"image" TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY("idpet" AUTOINCREMENT)); // <-- Aitoincrement
```

si el desarrollo es en Kotlin o Java / android solo agrega integer primary key autoincement a tu sentencia string de sqlite

resumen: verifica si a todas tu llaves primarias (id, int pk) de cada tabla le haz puesto "autoincrement"si no simpleemte agregaselo